# Efficient Algorithm for finding closest match in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-databases

Edit: to include concrete explanation of my problem (as correctly deduced by  Billiska):
"Set A is the set of users. set B is the set of products. each user rates one or more products. the rating is 1 to 10. you want to deduce for each user, who is the other user that has the most similar taste to him."

"The other half is choosing how exactly do you want to rank similarity of A-elements." - this is also part of my problem. I feel that users who have rated similarly across the most products have the closed affinity, but at the same time I want to avoid user1 and user2  with many mediocre matches being matched ahead of user1 and user3 who have just a few very good matches (perhaps I need a non-linear score).

Disclaimer: I have never used a graph database.

I two sets of data A and B. A has a relationship with zero to many Bs. Each relationship has a fixed value.

e.g.

A1--5-->B10

A1--1-->B1000

So my initial thought "Yay, thats a graph, time to learn about graph databases!" but before I get too carried away.... the only reason for doing this so that I can answer the question....

For each A find the set of As that are most similar based on their weights, where I want to take in to consideration

- the difference in weights (assuming 1 to 10) so that 10 and 10 is scored higher than 10 and 1; but then I have an issue with how to handle where is is no pairing (or do I - I am just not sure)
- the number of vertices (ignoring weights) that two sets have in common. Intention is to rank two As with lots of vertices to the same Bs higher than two As that have just a single matching vertices.

What would the best approach be to doing this?

(Supplementary - as I realise this may count a second question): How would that approach change if the set of A was in the millions and B in the 100 thousands and I needed real-time answers?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't follow those specifications. Are the edges weighted, and if so, how do determine their weights? Is the graph directed or undirected? Are the vertices weighted, and if so, how to determine weights? Is this possibly related to [weighted bipartite mathings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs)?

Comment: What similar means? Maybe you can define a distance between two elements of A (the sum of the squares of the differences of weight?)?

Comment: The most important thing now is probably to specify the question more precisely and clearly. (1) As I understand, the "B10" and "B1000" are just the names (IDs) of 2 elements in B. is that right? (2) as user189 said, specify the distance between 2 A-element mathematically.

Comment: To be honest, I could guess your application: set A is the set of users. set B is the set of products. each user rates one or more products. the rating is 1 to 10. you want to deduce for each user, who is the other user that has the most similar taste to him. Is that right? If so, I could help clarify half of the question. The other half is choosing how exactly do you want to rank similarity of A-elements.

Comment: Billiska has correctly deduced my problem. Hopefully that will open the discussion to some practical approaches to solving this. Its new territory for me and I would like to get quickly to "more or less right, with scope to improve the solution" and avoid any stupid dead ends in my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer. I don't fully understand the technique either. but I know it's very relevant.

If you view the data as a matrix. e.g. have the rows correspond to set A, have the columns correspond to set B, and the entries are the weight.
Then it's a matrix with some missing values.

One technique used in [recommender system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system) (under the category of collaborative filtering) is **low-rank approximation**.

It's based on the assumption that the said user-product rating matrix usually have low-rank.
In a rough sense, the said matrix have low-rank if the rows of many users could be expressed as linear combination of other users' row.

I hope this would give a start for further reading.

Yes, you could see in [low-rank approximation wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) that the technique can be used to guess the missing entries (the missing rating). I know it's a different problem, but related.

Comment: Have an upvote for both a relevant answer and the effort to work through the question, which I didn't understand.

Comment: @user2195559 If this answer is what you are looking for, you should tick the mark; that should not require any reputation, I think.

Comment: @G.Bach - I am not sure that the question is answered yet, am trying to understand if it is (this is all new to me, so will take me a little while to understand the answer and if it is applicable).